# RealmSwift query API gives Query<Date> instead of Date

Tags: swift, realm

I'm using RealmSwift to query for appointments on a specific day, so the method looks like:

```swift
func appointments(on date: Date) -> [Appointment] {
    realm.objects(Appointment.self)
        .where {
            Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, inSameDayAs: date)
        }
        .map { $0 }
}
```

But there are two issues:

1. Cannot convert value of type 'Query' to expected argument type 'Date'. Looks like the date property from Realm object is a `Query<Date>` instead of `Date`, how do I get the actual date from it?
2. Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to closure result type 'Query'. So realm expects a `Query<Bool>` instead of `Bool`, which isn't what I read on Realm's website regarding the query API: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/realm/realm-swift-query-api/

What could possibly be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: That `map` at the end looks unnecessary

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think it's to convert the results of a realm query to an in-memory `Array`. Perhaps writing it as `Array(realm.objects...)` reads better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm queries only supports a subset of operations you can do in normal Swift. See [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/crud/filter-data/#realm-swift-query-api) for a list of things it supports. This is enforced by using the [`Query<T>`](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/blob/752f8ae418f97c7e90c2c83ebeeb534c0357df4d/RealmSwift/Query.swift) type - it only declares the Realm-supported operations, like comparison operators, boolean operations, `in` for collections, etc. You can't pass a `Query<T>` around, as if it were a normal `T`.

Determining whether a date is in the same day as another date is not one of the supported operations. What you can do instead is find the beginning and end of `date`, and use comparison operators to check if the object's `date` is between them.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let start = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)
let end = calendar.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 1), to: start)
```

```
.where { $0.date >= start && $.date < end }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder what's the difference between the query API and simply `filter` with a closure?

Comment: @Heuristic You would be doing the whole filtering *in memory* if you do that. That may not be desirable.

Comment: Good to know @Sweeper, is there any documentation on this?

Comment: documentation on query API performs differently than `filter` that does everything in memory?

Comment: @Heuristic I don't know if it is documented. The `Results` object returned by `realm.objects(Appointment.self)` doesn't override the `Sequence.filter` method that takes a closure, so you'd be using the [default implementation in `Sequence`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L711), which iterates through everything, causing everything to be loaded into memory.

Comment: @Heuristic On the other hand, `where` [uses the `Query<Bool>` to construct an `NSPredicate`](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/blob/752f8ae418f97c7e90c2c83ebeeb534c0357df4d/RealmSwift/RealmCollection.swift#L723), which is then sent to the DB and the DB will do the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent answer by @sweeper. Another option is store the date also as a string as another object property.

So the Realm object would look like this

```
class ApptClass: Object {
  @Persisted var timestamp: Date!
  @Persisted var dateString = ""

  convenience init(withDate: Date) {
     self.init()
     self.timeStamp = withDate
     //get the date as a YYYY-MM-DD formatted string
     self.dateString = convertDateToDateString(d: withDate) //need to create this func
}
```

from there you can then do direct queries for specific dates

```
let results = realm.objects(ApptClass.self).where { $0.dateString == "2023-08-09" }
```

Edit: Per a note from @JoakimDanielson

> And you also need to make sure you update this property if the date
> changes

which, and one option, could be accomplished by using an unmanaged computed var that's backed by the timeStamp an dateString var. Something like this pseudo code

```
class ApptClass: Object {
      @Persisted var timestamp: Date!
      @Persisted var dateString = ""
      var useThisToSetTheDate: Date {
         set {
            set the timeStamp and the dateString
         }
         get {
            return timestamp
         }
```

Comment: And you also need to make sure you update this property if the date changes…

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes! Thank you for that comment. Included it in the answer.